# How do i select cells in a column that contain date type values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I want to look up the row that contains Transitioning EIN in the Unnamed 17 column and the date of 2021-01-29 in Unnamed 13 column.
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq3Nv.png)

I tried this:

```
df.loc[(df['Unnamed: 17']=='Transitioning EIN') & (df['Unnamed: 13']=="2021-01-29 00:00:00")]
```

which returns an empty dataframe. i can get the df back if i put just the transitioning ein condition but when i add in the date column condition it doesnt work. Any idea why?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Try doing each selection one at a time without the &.

Comment: please post some data in tabular format so that we can test it

Comment: Are you sure `2021-01-29 00:00:00` is a string in your dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read your datafile using `skiprows=5` before:

```
# or pd.read_csv('file.csv') if you have a csv file
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', skiprows=5, parse_dates=['Date Terminated'])
```

Then use:

```
m1 = df['Date Terminated'] == '2021-01-29 00:00:00'
m2 = df['Termination Type'] == 'Transitioning EIN'

df.loc[m1 & m2]
```

[image]